# how can I render .3ds file in browser?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I know a very little to make some 3d model using three.js. But is there a way to upload a file type of [.3ds] and then view the same file in the browser ? (m sure there is, but can't figure out how to though) Can we do something like holding the model and rotating the model in the browser just like in 3d software ?

I know this is a vague question. If anyone could tell me a starting point I will be on my way. But right now, I simply can't figure out where to start.

I thought three.js would be the right place (Might still be the right place) but I think its built to create 3d model in browser but not to import something like .3ds file and then rendering that file through its core or whatever...

And also can these uploaded file be rendered by WebGl renderer or Canvas. (oh, its so embarassing, I even don't know if I am getting my message correctly or not)

I simply dont't have a clue, giving me a starting point is all I want

Thnx

Comment: Read [this post](http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-workflow-tips.html) and try something. If you have trouble, show what you have tried and ask a specific question. I would suggest that you experiment with three.js first -- before attempting to import.

Comment: @WestLangley thnx... Thats exactly What I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be helpful for a future Googler...

I found this component called [k3d.js](http://k3d.ivank.net) which could parse .3ds, .obj, .md2, and Collada (.dae) file types. You can find the code examples in the demo tab. Hope, it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TDSLoader.js` from `three.js`. [Here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_3ds%20you%20can%20find%20an%20example%20from%20threejs.org).